# Change text to speech voice mac?

Tags: macos, mac, text-to-speech

Is it possible for me to change the text to speech voice (For example, right clicking any paragraph or text in TextEdit, clicking Speech --> Start Speaking) from the default American version to the UK voice (Daniel Compact, for example)?

I've tried to do this in voiceover but it does not affect the voice for Text to Speech.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to System Preferences -> Speech -> Select the "Text to Speech" tab, then choose the voice you want from the "System Voice" drop down.

On my Lion machine (not sure whether it's the same on Mountain Lion), I had to click "Customize..." from the dropdown then select "Daniel" to download from the "English (United Kingdom)" section.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the file sizes for the other voices can be quite large, so only download ones you want to use and delete ones you decide not to use.

Comment: if the voice does not seem to change even after selecting a new voice, try opening VoiceOver Utility and change the speech voice to something other than what it is listing. This tends to clear out the wonkiness. Mine was stuck on Alex since macOS Sierra until I stumbled on this. For extra fun, download the French Siri and set to that voice. All of your spoken text will have a French accent, kinda cool, n'est pas?